# Buying stocks for CALL OPTIONS that losing value

Tags: call-options

This is the scenario. Trader bought a **CALL OPTION** contract with a **strike price of $15** of a stock **XYZ** that expires in a month. But the price went down to **$12** in a week. The Trader sees this stock can rise in  an year.

What is the best strategy that the trader can choose to recoup the loss of value but gain in the rise in the stock in an year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roll the option to another call option on stock XYZ that expires in a year. Depending on your specific outlook, you have two options

1. Roll to the same strike a year out which would be more expensive and you'll have to add capital to the trade
2. Find a higher out of the money strike e.g. $25 a year out that costs the same as the $15 one month call

Another probably wise option would be that since your initial thesis for putting on the trade has so far been wrong, exit the trade, taking whatever value is left on the option and live to trade another day.

Comment: When I bought the contract, the price was $500, but lost the value and now it worth only $300. For both the strategies that you said, will I get only the value of the existing option at this moment which is $300 or will I get the value that I paid at the time of buy ($500)?

Comment: For any strategy, all you have to work with is the current value of contract. No strategy will automatically convert your $300 to $500 once executed. You bet $500...lost $300...and now, any new strategy is betting that remaining $300 with the possibility to make or lose money.

Answer (score 1):

If your $15 call expires in one month and you think that the stock can reach $15 in one year then you have a problem because your call expires much sooner.  You either roll the call out and possibly up (likely requiring additional capital) or you hope to get lucky.

You can use the [Broken Call Repair Strategy](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/optioninvestor/05/030105.asp) to repair your losing call position. It involves converting your long call to a bullish vertical with a lower long strike, ideally at no cost. It will lower your break even point but unfortunately, it will cap your potential profit which isn't part of your recovery premise.

Comment: Can I buy the 100 shares for $15, so I don't need to worry about the option expiring worthless?

Comment: Yes, you can buy the 100 shares for $15 but that doesn't change the fact that if your call expires OTM, it will be a total loss of premium.